# how to check up/down status of oracle reports server?

Tags: oracle, status, oraclereports

To check the status of database servers, I use tnsping utility.
Is there any similar utility for checking reports server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to the ReportServer admin console, that can be tough. But a call to /reports/rwservlet/showjobs?server= might do the trick for you. If you get a response, it confirms the server is up and running, and it'll show you any jobs that are running.

I've also implemented a procedure in the past that periodically runs a minimal report using utl_http and looks for a reasonable response. Then emails if it timesout or gets an HTTP error or report server error.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Jim Hudson, the Oracle Application Server Control is the easiest method to monitor your Oracle Report server(s).

However you can gain some information about the status from running the following command:

```
http://hostname.domain:port/reports/rwservlet/getserverinfo?server=yourReportServerName
```